# how to pass object from attr of button in django template to js

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to pass a Python object to JavaScript via the HTML attribute. I used the following codes, but I did not get an answer.

html code :

```
<button style="margin: 7px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary user-button-edit" user-arg="{{ user|safe }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
```

js code :

```
$(".user-button-edit").click(function() {
  var user = $(this).attr("user-arg");
  console.log(user);
  console.log(user.name);
  $("#Userpermissions_6").prop("checked",true);
})
```

the `user.name` --> `undefined`

Due to the presence of `'` in user object, it does not convert to Jason and gives an error.

Does anyone have a solution? (I do not want to create an attribute for each data.)

Comment: You are defining data-arg but retrieving user-arg

Comment: @Julien B. it was a typo . The problem is not that part